# What is the right way to include a list of items?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, punctuation

Example sentence:

> Please proceed to remove the agreed items from the list.

There was a former discussion on the items and I'd like to highlight the items again in the final action to take. Is the below sentence the right way to include the items?

> Please proceed to remove the agreed items(apple, orange, banana and
> pear) from the list.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather use a colon.

> Please proceed to remove the agreed items from the list: apple, orange, banana and pear.

---

[Colons](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/punctuation) are usually used to introduce lists while [parentheses](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/parenthesis) are used to give extra information.

---

Is it wrong? That depends on who you ask or what writting guidelines you follow. In my little experience, though, I've never seen a book use parentheses to introduce a list of more than two items.

Answer (score 1):

Its fine.  The parenthesis adds extra information, and isn't part of the grammar of the sentence. You're missing a space before the first bracket, but that is all.

If you find the list intrusive, you can simply add a second sentence.

> We agreed that the items apple, orange, banana and pear, were not required.  Please now proceed and remove these from the list.